# click function works with no label but not with a label

Tags: javascript, label

I have some JS for some radio buttons that works with no label wrapped around the radio buttons, but as soon as I add my label class to the radio buttons to style the radio buttons according to my theme, it stops working.

Here is the JS

```
$("#bn_only_yes").click(function(){
$("#bn_yes").attr("checked", "checked");
});
```

And here is the code it works fine with

```
<!-- IF B_BN_ONLY -->
<br />
<b>{L_30_0063}</b>
<br />
<input type="radio" name="buy_now_only" value="n" {BN_ONLY_N} id="bn_only_no">
{L_029}
<input type="radio" name="buy_now_only" value="y" {BN_ONLY_Y} id="bn_only_yes">
{L_030}
<!-- ENDIF -->

<!-- IF B_BN -->
<br />
<b>{L_496}</b>
<br />
<input type="radio" name="buy_now" id="bn_no" value="no" {BN_N}>
{L_029}
<input type="radio" name="buy_now" id="bn_yes" value="yes" {BN_Y}>
{L_030}
<input type="text" name="buy_now_price" id="bn" size="10" value="{BN_PRICE}">
<a href="converter.php" alt="converter" class="new-window">{CURRENCY}</a>
<!-- ENDIF -->
```

And here is the code that adds the label class styling to my inputs but the JS code stops working

```
<!-- IF B_BN_ONLY -->
<br />
<b>{L_30_0063}</b>
<br />
<label class="tz-radiobutton">
<input type="radio" name="buy_now_only" value="n" {BN_ONLY_N} id="bn_only_no">
{L_029}
</label>
<label class="tz-radiobutton">
<input type="radio" name="buy_now_only" value="y" {BN_ONLY_Y} id="bn_only_yes">
{L_030}
</label>
<!-- ENDIF -->

<!-- IF B_BN -->
<br />
<b>{L_496}</b>
<br />
<label class="tz-radiobutton">
<input type="radio" name="buy_now" id="bn_no" value="no" {BN_N}>
{L_029}
</label>
<label class="tz-radiobutton">
<input type="radio" name="buy_now" id="bn_yes" value="yes" {BN_Y}>
{L_030}
</label>
<input type="text" name="buy_now_price" id="bn" size="10" value="{BN_PRICE}">
<a href="converter.php" alt="converter" class="new-window">{CURRENCY}</a>
<!-- ENDIF -->
```

I have even tried adding the input ID to the label but it still won't work.

Anyone have any ideas how I can include the label class in the JS as well as the input ID.

**ADDING TZ-RADIOBUTTON CSS**

```
header, footer, article, nav, #tz-hmenu-bg, .tz-sheet, .tz-hmenu a, .tz-vmenu a, .tz-   slidenavigator > a, .tz-checkbox:before, .tz-radiobutton:before
{
-webkit-background-origin: border !important;
-moz-background-origin: border !important;
background-origin: border-box !important;

header, footer, article, nav, #tz-hmenu-bg, .tz-sheet, .tz-slidenavigator > a, .tz- checkbox:before, .tz-radiobutton:before
{
display: block;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
}

label.tz-radiobutton:before
{
background: #FFFFFF;
-webkit-border-radius:8px;
-moz-border-radius:8px;
border-radius:8px;
border:1px solid #8496A4;
margin:0 auto;
width:16px;
height:16px;
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: top;
content: ' ';
}
label.tz-radiobutton
{
cursor: pointer;
font-size: 13px;
font-family: Arial, 'Arial Unicode MS', Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
line-height: 16px;
display: inline-block;
color: #323C43 !important;
position: relative;
}

.tz-radiobutton>input[type="radio"]
{
vertical-align: baseline;
margin: 0 5px 0 0;
}

label.tz-radiobutton.active:before
{
background: #FFFFFF;
-webkit-border-radius:8px;
-moz-border-radius:8px;
border-radius:8px;
border:1px solid #8496A4;
margin:0 auto;
width:16px;
height:16px;
display: inline-block;
}

label.tz-radiobutton.hovered:before
{
background: #FFFFFF;
-webkit-border-radius:8px;
-moz-border-radius:8px;
border-radius:8px;
border:1px solid #8496A4;
margin:0 auto;
width:16px;
height:16px;
display: inline-block;
}

label.tz-radiobutton input[type="radio"]
{
display: none;
}

label.tz-radiobutton.tz-checked:after
{
content: url('../images/radiobuttonicon.png');
position: absolute;
line-height: 12px;
left: 2px;
top: 2px;
}
```

Comment: It shouldn't matter if there's a label when you're using input's id. How does it not work?

Comment: I made a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/5h0sjtqf/1/) with your HTML including the labels. It works as expected: When you click `#bn_only_yes` then `#bn_yes` gets attribute `checked="checked"`

Comment: BTW, there's a closing `}` missing in CSS, line above `header, footer, ...`.

Comment: Complete CSS added to new [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/5h0sjtqf/5/). Result: the JS still works!

Comment: yeah the JS has lots more lines I only posted the lines I am having problem with

Comment: yes I know it works but it will not add the checked picture from the css so it looks like it is not working

Answer (score 0):

You will never see the checked input because of

```
label.tz-radiobutton input[type="radio"] {
display: none;
}
```

Comment: the label adds a style to the input in my theme not to the text, the bit you see that is {L_029} reads a file named messages.inc.php and returns some text from messages.inc.php that is $MSG['029'] = "No"; basically the {L_029} returns the text NO. Why would I add a class of radiobutton to some text

Comment: Just tried that makes absolutely no difference even when moving the ending </label> up so it just wraps the input

Comment: can you post the class 'tz-radiobutton' used and the browser used for your test ?

Comment: Please use this code to debug if the click is fired $("#bn_only_yes").click(function(){
    console.log('checked');
    $("#bn_yes").attr("checked", "checked");
});

Comment: I will post the "tz-radiobutton" CSS and I have tested that on the latest versions of FF, Chrome and IE it works perfectly but not when that JS is involved, the "tz-radiobutton" still looks as it should but stops the JS working. "tz-radiobutton follows next.

Comment: will add the css anything to do with tz-radiobutton in my first post

Comment: I changed my answer can you check the new one Please.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing your CSS I guess you want to add a style to the label of `#btn_yes` on click: `label.tz-radiobutton.tz-checked:after {}` and display an icon with it.

1) In the CSS you've posted is a closing `}` missing in the line above `header, footer, ...`.

2) To get the style working you need to add a class `tz-checked` to the label:

```
$("#bn_only_yes").click(function(){
    $("#bn_yes").parent().addClass('tz-checked');
});
```

[The third FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/5h0sjtqf/8/).

And if you want to set the attribute `checked` on the checkbox too:

```
$("#bn_only_yes").click(function(){
    $("#bn_yes").attr('checked', 'checked').parent().addClass('tz-checked');
});
```

Comment: your a star. Thanks loads for this with a few tweaks to what you supplied me I have it working great here is the code with my tweaks. [code] $("#bn_yes").attr("checked", "checked");
      $("#bn_yes").parent().addClass("tz-checked");
      $("#bn_no").parent().removeClass("tz-checked"); [/code]